# Patch 6788 for Free Extension Kinento Payment Order Reminder

Tags: adminhtml, supee-6788

I have noticed that the well known and excellent free Payment Order Reminder Module Kinento see
https://github.com/Kinento/order-reminders has not been updated for Patch SUPEE-6788.

I have tried doing this manually without success.

The question is: does anyone know what I am doing wrong with following lines of code?

Path:

```
Kinento\Reminder\controllers\Adminhtml\Reminder\
```

SendController.php

```
class Kinento_Reminder_Adminhtml_Reminder_SendController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
```

ViewController.php

```
class Kinento_Reminder_Adminhtml_Reminder_ViewController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
```

Path:
Kinento\Reminder\etc\config.xml

```
<admin>
  <routers>
    <adminhtml>
      <args>
        <modules>
          <reminder before="Mage_Adminhtml">Kinento_Reminder_Adminhtml_Reminder</reminder>
        </modules>
      </args>
    </adminhtml>
  </routers>
</admin>
```

and

```
<menu>
  <sales>
    <children>
       <reminder translate="title" module="reminder">
         <title>Order Reminders</title>
         <sort_order>700</sort_order>
         <action>adminhtml/reminder/view_main</action>
       </reminder>
    </children>
  </sales>
</menu>
```

When trying to view the Order Reminders Grid I see only a blank page

Appreciate the Forum help.

Thanks

Phil

Comment: updated my question to be more precise

Comment: I think your `<action>` in the `<menu>` tab is wrong. It should probably be `<action>adminhtml/reminder/view</action>`. There is actually no `mainAction` in the ViewController.php. At least not in the default extension.

Comment: Sadly this did not solve the problem ... I still get a page saying the page does not exist.
Following is the original version of Kinento prior to SUPEE-6788 Patch .
https://github.com/Kinento/order-reminders
What would you change in the code from https://github.com/Kinento/order-reminders to make it SUPEE-6788 compliant?

Comment: OK, found the solution through someones help:
It should be <reminder before="Mage_Adminhtml">Kinento_Reminder_Adminhtml</reminder>
and
<action>adminhtml/reminder_view</action>